# Every line integral starting and ending at the boundary vanishes implies that the vector field is $0$?

Tags: vector-analysis, examples-counterexamples, vector-fields, line-integrals, divergence-operator

Let $V\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be compact and possess a piecewise smooth boundary $\partial V$. Let $\mathbf F$ be a continuously differentiable vector field defined on a neighborhood of $V$.
Suppose that for every piecewise smooth oriented path $C\subset V$ that starts and ends at $\partial V$ the line integral
$$
  \int_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = 0.
$$
If $\nabla\cdot\mathbf F = 0$, can we conclude that $\mathbf F = \mathbf 0$?

In case the above is not true, is there a simple counter-example?

---

**My Attempt:** Without the vanishing divergence assumption, I came up with the following counter-example. Let $V$ be the unit ball centered at the origin. Then, $\mathbf F = x \mathbf i + y \mathbf j + z\mathbf k$ satisfies the assumptions and $\mathbf F \neq \mathbf 0$.

On the other hand, assuming both divergence and curl vanishes (and $V$ is simply connected), then there exists $\Phi:V\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla \Phi = \mathbf F$. Thus, $\nabla^2 \Phi = 0$ and since $\Phi$ is constant in $\partial V$, then we can conclude that $\Phi$ is constant ([Dirichlet problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_problem)). Thus, $\mathbf F = \mathbf 0$.

Assuming that only the divergence vanishes, I imagine there is a counter-example, but I couldn't find one.

---

**Update:** $\mathbf F$ must be $\mathbf 0$.

Let $\Gamma\subset V$ be a closed path. Let $C_n$ be a path that starts at some point in $\partial V$ goes through $\Gamma$ $n$ times and returns to some point in $\partial V$. We know that the line integral over $C_n$ is $0$ for every $n$. Thus, the line integral over $\Gamma$ must also vanish. Since $\Gamma$ is an arbitrary closed path, then $\mathbf F$ is conservative and we end up with the Dirichlet problem.

Is this correct?

*Edit:* @TedShifrin made me realize that the above is valid only if $V$ is connected. However, I imagine we can apply the above reasoning for each connected component.

Comment: Are your paths $C$ closed? Can they go through the interior of $V$ or must they stay on $\partial V\,?$

Comment: They are not necessarily closed. Yes, they can go through the interior of $V$.

Comment: The original question said that the path started and ended on $\partial V$, not that it was a closed path. It makes a difference.  If the path must start and end at the same point, take $\Phi(x) = \|x\|^{-1/2}$. $\partial V$ may now have two components.

Comment: As I said, they are not necessarily closed. They just have to start and end at $\partial V$.

Comment: As I stated the problem, I agree that $\partial V$ may have two components. However, I do not see how $\Phi(x) = \| x \|^{-1/2}$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: The editing confused me. No, if you go from one level set of a harmonic function to another, the net work will not be zero.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I did not edit the question, you can check in the [log](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4763625/revisions). The only change I made was to make it clear the vector field is defined in a neighborhood of $V$. But I suppose that is okay.

Comment: It seems to me that your argument needs some fleshing out, but is essentially correct.

Comment: As I understand it, you're implying that the two segments $\ A,B\ $ of each $\ C_n\ $ that go from $\ \partial V\ $ to $\ \Gamma\ $ and from $\ \Gamma\ $ back to $\ \partial V\ $ are independent of $\ n\ $, so \begin{align}0&=\int_\limits{C_n}\mathbf{F\cdot dr}\\&=\int_ 
A\mathbf{F\cdot dr}+n\int_\Gamma\mathbf{F\cdot dr}+\int_ 
B\mathbf{F\cdot dr}\ ,\end{align}
implying $$\int_\Gamma\mathbf{F\cdot dr}=-\frac{1}{n}\left(\int_ 
A\mathbf{F\cdot dr}+\int_ 
B\mathbf{F\cdot dr}\right)\rightarrow0$$ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $. That argument seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: Your update was added … and I was sloppily confused. My fault.